# Why my OnLongClickListener is not working?

Tags: android, imageview, onlongclicklistener

I want to show the EXIF of a picture when I perform a long click over it. So I implemented this:

```
    picture.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() { 
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            ...
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Problem is that the code is not executed. I added `android:longClickable="true"` into the xml, without success.

Funny thing is that it works for `OnClick`, but it doesn't for `OnLongClick`... Maybe it has to do with the fact that my picture is and extension of ImageView, the (very nice!) class TouchImageView here:

https://github.com/MikeOrtiz/TouchImageView/blob/master/src/com/example/touch/TouchImageView.java

What am I doing wrong??

Thanks!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`TouchImageView` in `OnTouchListener` always calls `return true;` (line 112 in file). That's why `OnLongClickListener` is not working.

Comment: You're right, changed the return value to false and longclick works. I wonder if I can leave it at false without burning my city. Thanks!!!

Comment: No, setting return value to 'false' is not an option for me, since when resizing or moving (the whole point of TouchImageView) it also performs longclick. It seems I should somehow add longclick to the TouchImageView class itself.

Comment: This is how it's done in `android.view.View` class http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/4.1.1_r1/android/view/View.java#View.checkForLongClick%28int%29 Another option is using `GestureDetector` with `onLongPress` method.